# Windows Gstreamer ALSA Alternative?

Tags: python, windows, gstreamer, alsa

Does anyone know an alternative to ALSA that can be used on windows, with gstreamer, and how to install it, and where to find python bindings for it if it needs it?
thanks xxx

Comment: ALSA is the sound system used by Linux, so I doubt that you can use an ALSA sink on Windows.

Comment: SDL does a decent job of abstracting sound interfaces in a platform-independent way. PyGame contains an interface to SDL and works on many platforms. Such abstraction, of course, sets many limitations, but maybe it will still do for you.

Comment: @9000: you might want to transform your comment into an answer so that James can accept it.

Comment: @9000 yes please do what cristian suggests :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL does a decent job of abstracting sound interfaces in a platform-independent way. PyGame contains an interface to SDL and works on many platforms. Such abstraction, of course, sets many limitations, but maybe it will still do for you.

<sub>Converted from a comment.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is still relevant, but I had the exact same problem today. I got around it by using "autoaudiosink".

That way I got the minimal example on the following website to work in Windows XP

http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/08/28/getting-started-with-gstreamer-with-python/

Here is my version of the code (essentially the same except for the alsasink)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst
import pygtk
import gtk

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("mypipeline")

        self.audiotestsrc = gst.element_factory_make("audiotestsrc", "audio")
        self.pipeline.add(self.audiotestsrc)

        self.sink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "sink")
        self.pipeline.add(self.sink)

        self.audiotestsrc.link(self.sink)

        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

start=Main()
gtk.main()
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: yea.... i moved to linux a long time ago :D xx fedora 16 atm :) now if i so wish i could use ALSA sinks, but to be perfectly honest i just haven't used gstreamer for ages xx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on Windows the SDK installer doesn't actually install the bindings to any location visible to the Python interpreter. You can find the files at `sdk\bindings\python\v2.6\lib\site-packages`. Copy the contents of the directory to your Python installation's `site-packages`, and you should be able to import the library.

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: Ok, then you need to also copy the dll from `sdk/bindings/python/v2.6/lib/gstreamer-0.10` to your `Python2.6/DLLs`.

Comment: Are you testing this from IDLE? Did you restart IDLE after copying the DLL? I'm not sure what else could be wrong, as I've just tried the steps myself, and `import pygst` works for me.

Are you sure you have the file `Python26/DLLs/libgstpython-v2.6.dll` ? Are you using the 32bit or 64bit version of Python?

Comment: @shang i am using 32 bit, im using commandline , and im certain i have libgstpython-v2.6.dll :( im cursed technologically....

Comment: @shang, i have fixed my original problem by changing to a beta version, (which deeply troubles me, i would have thought any problems would have persisted...) but i now have the problems as defined in the question now xx do you have any ideas? :( xx

Answer (score 0):

9000's answer, sdl, and autoaudiosrc/sink are the answer :)